# Параметризованный запрос не использует отфильтрованный индекс

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица событий со статусом и источником события:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InteropTask] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
   ,[Source] [int] NOT NULL
   ,[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL
   ,[Category] [int] NOT NULL
   ,[Status] [int] NOT NULL
   ,[Parameters] [nvarchar](MAX) NOT NULL
   ,CONSTRAINT [PK_InteropTask] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
    [Id] ASC
    )
)
```

И из кода C# генерируется запрос вида:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [Category], [Created], [Id], [Parameters], [Source], [Status]
FROM [dbo].[InteropTask]
WHERE ([Source] = @p_0)
AND ([Status] = @p_1)
',N'@p_0 int,@p_1 int',@p_0=2,@p_1=0
```

Далее для удобства смотрел из SSMS такой запрос:

```
declare @p_0 int  = 2
declare @p_1 int = 0

SELECT
    [Category]
   ,[Created]
   ,[Id]
   ,[Parameters]
   ,[Source]
   ,[Status]
FROM [dbo].[InteropTask]
WHERE ([Source] = @p_0)
AND ([Status] = @p_1)
```

И захотелось мне попробовать фильтрованный индекс создать. Ну вот например такой:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_1111] ON [dbo].[InteropTask]
(
[Source] ASC,
[Status] ASC
)
WHERE ([status] = (0))
```

При этом вижу что в запросе этот индекс не используется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только если убрать параметризацию, тогда индекс начинает использоваться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перечитал офдок (Create Filtered Indexes [en](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15)  [ru](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15)), но так и не понял, что оптимизатору не нравится.

Пробовал создавать индекс с  `WHERE ([status] = (0) and source = (2))` - эффект тот же.

В идеале хочется, чтобы параметризованный запрос видел индекс. Версия сервера: SQL Server 2012 SP4

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: "никак".

> Фильтрованный индекс невозможно использовать, если значение представлено в виде параметра. В случае параметра генерируется план для «средней температуры по больнице». Для использования же фильтрованных индексов (а если обобщить – для построения оптимальных планов под конкретные значения) надо вместо параметров использовать константы. Значения параметров подставляются в уже готовый план. И значение параметра может оказаться вне фильтра, а значит и использовать этот индекс с параметрами никак нельзя

Update: для linq который транслируется в SQL можно указать чтобы генерировался не код `WHERE ([Field] = @p_0)` а `WHERE ([Field] = 42`: нужно чтобы константа была именно константой

См. тут: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27225626/5752652

Comment: ну, вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686422/sql-server-parameterized-query-does-not-use-non-clustered-filtered) пишут, что, чтобы индекс таки подцепился, можно использовать `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. Но тут уже надо будет взвешивать "за" и "против".

Comment: Я как бы имел в виду вот это место из ответа: _You can add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the statement so the runtime values of these are taken into account (basically they are replaced by literals with the runtime value) but that will mean a recompile every execution._ Конструкция с WITH INDEX - это уже другой вариант, который там предложили.